# How can I login with redirection (using POST)

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, yew

I'm still trying to learn Rust and the YEW Framework (0.20).
Following the YEW tutorial only teaches you to Get data, and many online examples are not working for my case.
Is there a simple way to do this in YEW?

What I'm trying to do is :

1. Do a simple login to the backend (using POST).
2. Get/set the value of the cookie on the front end.

Note: Since the login page usually comes with a redirect, I have to get the value before the redirect.

Working example in RUST + Reqwest. I can achieve this by disable redirection.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
    .cookie_store(true)
    .redirect(reqwest::redirect::Policy::none())
    .build()?;

    let res = client
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8888/login")
        .body("this is the body")
        .send()
        .await?;
    println!("Status: {}", res.status());
    // cookie can be found here.....
    for x in res.cookies()
    {
        println!("{:?}",x)
    }

    // cookie used here .....
    let res = client
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:8888/")
        .body("this is the body")
        .send()
        .await?;
    println!("Status: {}", res.status());
    println!("text: {}", res.text().await?);
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found some code that works at :
https://github.com/wpcodevo/rust-yew-signup-signin/blob/master/src/api/user_api.rs

```
pub async fn api_login_user(credentials: &str) -> Result<UserLoginResponse, String> {
let response = match http::Request::post("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .credentials(http::RequestCredentials::Include)
    .body(credentials)
    .send()
    .await
{
    Ok(res) => res,
    Err(_) => return Err("Failed to make request".to_string()),
};

if response.status() != 200 {
    let error_response = response.json::<ErrorResponse>().await;
    if let Ok(error_response) = error_response {
        return Err(error_response.message);
    } else {
        return Err(format!("API error: {}", response.status()));
    }
}

let res_json = response.json::<UserLoginResponse>().await;
match res_json {
    Ok(data) => Ok(data),
    Err(_) => Err("Failed to parse response".to_string()),
}}
```

but for my solution i just use some part of the code. and change the import into gloo_net instead of reqwasm::http

```
    let response = Request::post("http://127.0.0.1:8888/login")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/text")
    .credentials(http::RequestCredentials::Include)
    .body(credentials)
    .send()
    .await
    .unwrap();
```